# Delete from multiple tables with MyISAM

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I already tried lots and lots of combinations but none seem to work =(

I have these two SQL commands:

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM infogt2000_partner_lead_invoice WHERE infogt2000_partner_lead_invoice_lead_id = ".$id_invoice;
$sql = "DELETE FROM infogt2000_partner_lead  WHERE infogt2000_partner_lead_id = ".$id;
```

And they have to execute "together". Well, if I delete an information from partner_lead it also has to delete the same info from infogt2000_partner_lead_invoice. 
The id in infogt2000_partner_lead_id and infogt2000_partner_lead_invoice_lead_id are the same but I cannot write it correctly.

I am currently using MySQL and the type is MyISAM

Comment: Can you use InnoDB instead and are you familiar with foreign keys?

Comment: Cascading foreign keys is the proper way to only execute 1 query to do what you want. otherwise you will need to run 2 queries.

Comment: Are you using mysqli_query or some similar call after each of these two sql statements?  Can you show the code surrounding the two statements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gess you will need to use inner join:

```
DELETE infogt2000_partner_lead_invoice, infogt2000_partner_lead
FROM infogt2000_partner_lead_invoice
INNER JOIN infogt2000_partner_lead
WHERE infogt2000_partner_lead_invoice.infogt2000_partner_lead_invoice_lead_id = infogt2000_partner_lead.infogt2000_partner_lead_id
AND infogt2000_partner_lead_invoice_lead_id = $id
```

Answer (score 0):

You should consider converting your database tables to InnoDB so that you can create foreign key constraints to cascade on delete. Otherwise, you must write multiple queries, starting from the lowest item in the chain of hierarchy working your way up to the parent-most table. Eg: delete grandchildren, then children, then parents.

Comment: I did that. The first command is the child table and the other is the parent but when it executes, just the parent get deleted

Comment: What happens when you `SELECT * FROM infogt2000_partner_lead_invoice WHERE infogt2000_partner_lead_invoice_lead_id = ".$id_invoice;` -- do you see any data?

Comment: Another benefit of InnoDB is that it's transactional, so if any of the queries fail you can rollback to ensure data integrity

Comment: I can ask if it can be converted but I don't believe the company will change it...